# pure white error does not show any data when deploying next js 13 to cpanel

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, cpanel, next.js13

I followed the instructions on next js homepage:

here is the file: package.json

```
{
  "name": "app-me",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "@types/node": "20.5.0",
    "@types/react": "18.2.20",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.7",
    "@types/react-slick": "^0.23.10",
    "@types/video.js": "^7.3.52",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.15",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.1",
    "eslint": "8.47.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.17",
    "framer-motion": "^10.16.1",
    "mongodb": "^5.8.1",
    "mongoose": "^7.4.4",
    "next": "13.4.17",
    "plyr": "^3.7.8",
    "postcss": "8.4.28",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.8.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.10.1",
    "react-slick": "^0.29.0",
    "sharp": "^0.32.5",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.3",
    "typescript": "5.1.6",
    "video.js": "^8.5.2",
    "sass": "^1.66.0",
    "sass-loader": "^13.3.2"
  }
}
```

and here is the file: server.js

```
const { createServer } = require('http')
const { parse } = require('url')
const next = require('next')
 
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const hostname = 'localhost'
const port = 3000
// when using middleware `hostname` and `port` must be provided below
const app = next({ dev, hostname, port })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()
 
app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer(async (req, res) => {
    try {
      // Be sure to pass `true` as the second argument to `url.parse`.
      // This tells it to parse the query portion of the URL.
      const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true)
      const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl
 
      if (pathname === '/a') {
        await app.render(req, res, '/a', query)
      } else if (pathname === '/b') {
        await app.render(req, res, '/b', query)
      } else {
        await handle(req, res, parsedUrl)
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error occurred handling', req.url, err)
      res.statusCode = 500
      res.end('internal server error')
    }
  })
    .once('error', (err) => {
      console.error(err)
      process.exit(1)
    })
    .listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`> Ready on http://${hostname}:${port}`)
    })
})
```

this is my website https://thichphim.net/
and here is the image, the app is running no error message pops out, i also ran npm install
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZDFr.png)
I also made sure I ran npm run build under localhost